# Combine multiple releations into single array prisma

Tags: prisma

I'm starting with primsa for the first time and I was wondering if there is an easy way of combining a relation.

E.g.

```
model Person {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  name      String
  gender    String

  mother   Person? @relation("Mother", fields: [motherId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  motherId String?

  father   Person? @relation("Father", fields: [fatherId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  fatherId String?

  images HerringGullImage[]

  childeren1 Person [] @relation("Mother")
  childeren2 Person [] @relation("Father")
}
```

So now you have childeren from the mother and childeren for the father. I was wondering if you can combine these in prisma, or if I have to combine these after in code

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by combining the relations? Can't you just have a single children relation field?

Comment: @NurulSundarani and what would be the string in the @relation?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Do you intend to achieve a case where children of Mother and children of father are different?